# Parameters with no mutators and accessors (setters/getters) along with the parameters interceptor in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, interceptor, struts2-interceptors

In the following action class, I'm using the parameters interceptor.

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value = "struts-default")
@InterceptorRefs(@InterceptorRef(value="store", params={"operationMode", "AUTOMATIC"}))
public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ValidationAware, Preparable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    //Getters and setters.

    public TestAction() {}

    @Action(value = "TestMessage",
        results = {
            @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Test"}),
            @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Test.jsp")},
        interceptorRefs={
            @InterceptorRef(value="paramsPrepareParamsStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "param1, param2", "params.excludeParams", "extraParam", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})
        })
    public String insert() {
        // Do something. Add or update a row to the database (one at a time).
        addActionMessage("Action message");
        addActionError("Error message");
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "Test",
    results = {
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location = "Test.jsp"),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Test.jsp")},
    interceptorRefs = {
        @InterceptorRef(value = "paramsPrepareParamsStack", params = {"params.acceptParamNames", "param1, param2", "params.excludeParams", "extraParam", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true", "validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
    public String load() throws Exception {
        // This method is just required to return an initial view on page load.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {}
}
```

The following is `<s:form>`:

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="Test" validate="true" id="dataForm" name="dataForm">
    <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
        <s:actionmessage theme="jquery"/>
    </s:if>

    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
        <s:actionerror theme="jquery"/>
    </s:if>

    <s:hidden name="param1"/>
    <s:hidden name="param2"/>
    <s:hidden name="extraParam"/>
    <s:submit value="Submit" action="TestMessage"/>
</s:form>
```

Here, the hidden form field `extraParam` is not declared and consequently, has no setter and getter in the action class.

In this case, the following message appears on the server terminal, when this form is submitted.

> SEVERE: Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable
>   this message): Unexpected Exception caught setting 'extraParam' on
>   'class actions.TestAction: Error setting expression 'extraParam' with
>   value ['', ]

`params.excludeParams` does not exclude the parameter `extraParam` as in the action class.

Can we somehow prevent such exceptions while using the parameters interceptor. Such messages are unnecessarily added to action messages and displayed through `<s:actionmessage/>`, if used, when they are not supposed to be shown at all.

---

If this `paramsPrepareParamsStack` is replaced with `defaultStack` in the action class then, such messages don't appear. It just gives a warning as follows.

> WARNING: Parameter [extraParam] is on the excludeParams list of
>   patterns!

<sub>Please don't just say, *set `struts.devMode` to `false` to disable
such messages.*</sub>

Comment: Why do you think that parameters are inherited?

Comment: "*parameters are inherited?*" I don't understand!

Comment: if you have some configuration and it has some parameters to the action or interceptor, and you extend them from the parent package and it becomes not the same as if you specify an annotation on the class or on the method.

Comment: @RomanC : You may please answer the question. I don't understand the thing you're mentioning.

Comment: Please add answer(s), if someone has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already said in the comment that interceptor parameters are not inherited by the interceptor configs of the parent packages if you define your own set of parameters that override the default settings. See [Interceptor Parameter Overriding Inheritance](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/interceptors.html#Interceptors-InterceptorParameterOverridingInheritance).

There are also some techniques used to obtain two different maps of interceptor parameters, see [Getting Interceptor Parameters in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16467068/573032).

The convention plugin creates XWork package configs that inherited from some parent package. See my answer for [Struts 2 Convention Plugin Define Multiple Parent Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14213793/573032).

So, all you have to do is to override the default parameter set by the parent configuration if you want to add your own parameters to the set. Either `interceptor` tag or `interceptor-stack` tag and you should do it for each `interceptor-ref` tag.

The convention plugin uses [`@InterceprorRef`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-plugins/struts2-convention-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/convention/annotation/InterceptorRef.html) annotation for the same purpose but with a caveat that if applied on the class, it applies on each action of that class. So, be careful when using this annotation on the class level. You are overriding the interceptor stack parameters, so you should use a prefix followed by dot of the interceptor name referenced in the stack for each parameter name, but this only works if you have unique names of the `interceptor-ref`s in the stack.

If you have two references of the `params` interceptor in the `paramsPrepareParamsStack` then you can't override the second `params` `interceptor-ref` unless you create your own interceptor stack and specify parameter overrides on each reference of the interceptor.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to put it into practice later on.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look at the `paramsPrepareParamsStack`:

```
 <interceptor-stack name="paramsPrepareParamsStack">
      <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="params">
          <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
      </interceptor-ref>
      <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
      <interceptor-ref name="params">
          <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
       </interceptor-ref>
       <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
       <interceptor-ref name="validation">
           <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
       </interceptor-ref>
       <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
           <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
       </interceptor-ref>
 </interceptor-stack>
```

There are 2 `params` interceptors. When you are setting `excludeParams` parameter in your action class, then this is probably set for the first `params` interceptor - parameter for the second interceptor stays default. Now, when the second `params` interceptor (with default `excludeParams`) is invoked, then given exception is thrown.

You can try to duplicate setting of the `excludeParams` parameter to set its also for the second interceptor:

```
 @InterceptorRef(value = "paramsPrepareParamsStack", params = {"params.acceptParamNames", "param1, param2", "params.excludeParams", "extraParam", "params.excludeParams", "extraParam", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true", "validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
```

Comment: The code snippet in the question is just an example. In reality, there are no defined parameters as `extraParam` as even end users can supply any number of malicious parameters (depending upon the length of the URL they are interested in) that can cause such an exception as mentioned in the question. `params.acceptParamNames` should only accept those parameters which are listed. The rest must be forbidden **without causing such messages as in the question to appear**.

Comment: As I mentioned, there are 2 `params` interceptors in `paramsPrepareParamsStack`. When you are setting `params.acceptParamNames` this is set only for the first interceptor. You nedd to set this parameter also for the second interceptor.

Comment: Specifying either `params.acceptParamNames` or `params.excludeParams` twice on the parameters interceptor doesn't make a difference. It doesn't prevent the exception as mentioned in the question. Therefore, I currently don't consider accepting the answer so that it is listed in the [unanswered question list](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered). If you encounter a solution either deliberately or accidently later on, please don't forget to update the answer, no matter how much time it takes, may be years. This is the only place for me where I can learn. Thanks.

Comment: I accidently awarded the bounty to a wrong answer, first time. I feel guilty and shame for it. The action once completed can never be undone. Please forgive me. I really apologize to my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying exactly,

sample code following as:

```
<s:form action="save" method="post">
    <s:textfield key="personBean.firstName" /> 
    <s:textfield key="personBean.lastName" /> 
    <s:textfield key="personBean.email" />
    <s:textfield key="personBean.phoneNumber" />
    <s:select key="personBean.sport" list="sports" />
    <s:radio key="personBean.gender" list="genders" />
    <s:select key="personBean.residency" list="states" listKey="stateAbbr" listValue="stateName"/>
    <s:checkbox key="personBean.over21" />
    <s:checkboxlist key="personBean.carModels" list="carModelsAvailable" />
    <s:submit key="submit" />
</s:form>
```

Maybe its not working goto this link:

- (http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html)
- (http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-interceptors-tutorial-1.html)
- (http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html)
- (http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html)

Comment: Thank you but in fact, I don't understand.